# Update with firebase in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've created recyclerview that has retrieve data that contain name, phone, zone, status etc. from firebase. Now I want to implement itemclicklistener with firebase that let user to click on the item and pop up a dialog to update the status value from firebase.

My database as example:

```
   public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        studentMatrik = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMatrik);
        studentPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentPhone);
        studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
        studentStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentStatus);
        studentMail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMail);
        studentCon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentCon);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        buttonMap = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
        buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", studentMail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", studentCon.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Address", studentAddress.getText().toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    String name = studentName.getText().toString();
                    databaseReference.child("student").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String id = snapshot.getKey();
                                String studentName = snapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);

                                if(name.equals(studentName)) {

                                }
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: May be you could pass that data snapshot through your listener.

Comment: @Akhilesh Awasthi where to insert?

Comment: It is pretty unclear which problem you have. Why didnt you tell?

Comment: @greenapps updated... the itemview are data retrieve from firebase I want to update studentStatus value to yes in firebase when checkbox is check

Comment: you want to update user Info right.?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student implements Parcelable{

        private String name;

     //      getter /setter 

   // Parcelable implementation 


}
```

and on your `check Listener`

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
//pass object that contains user info and display that info in Custom Dialog 
UserInfoDIalog infoDialog= new UserInfoDIalog (mContext,userObject);
            infoDialog.show();


    }
}
```

and then on `dialog` submission `update` that child `node`.!

```
mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(userObject);
```